# bilinear complex least squares method

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, complex-numbers, matrix-calculus, least-squares

I want to minimise S, which is given by,

$S = \sum_{i,j} \frac{1}{\sigma^2_{ij}}|V_{ij} - g_i g^*_j V^{model}_{ij}|^2$,

where $V_{ij}$ and $V^{model}_{ij}$ are the observed and model complex visibilities (this is a (M x 1) vector) both of which are known, $\sigma_{ij}$ is the error and $g_i$ and $g_j$ are the complex gains that I am minimising S for.

In my case I am only interested to solve for the phases of the complex gains assuming their amplitude is 1. I can therefore write the following:

$V^{model, corrupted}_{ij} = g_i g^*_j V^{model}_{ij} = e^{i (\phi_i - \phi_j)} V^{model}_{ij} = e^{i f \phi} V^{model}_{ij}$,

where f is a (M x N) matrix and $\phi$ is a (N x 1) vector of the gain phases (for N=4 antennas I have M=N(N-1)/2 visibilities), so that

$\begin{pmatrix} 
\phi_1 - \phi_2 \\ 
\phi_1 - \phi_3 \\ 
\phi_1 - \phi_4 \\ 
\phi_2 - \phi_3 \\
\phi_2 - \phi_4 \\
\phi_3 - \phi_4 \\
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
    0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix} \cdot
\begin{pmatrix} \phi_1 & \phi_2 & \phi_3 & \phi_4 \end{pmatrix} = f\phi$

I can now minimise the expression S, using for example a gradient descent algorithm, for the vector $\phi$. However, as you can imagine as the number of antennas increases the problem becomes more and more computationally demanding.

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to approach my problem, either analytic (doubtful) or with a more sophisticated algorithm that takes advantage of the fact that my solution has the form that I want (i.e. $g_j = e^{i \phi_j}$).

Comment: I'm confused: are the $\sigma_{ij}$ known quantities? Do they depend on the $g_i$?

Comment: The $\sigma_{ij}$ are also known. Sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: Is $V^{model}$ real and symmetric, by the way?

Comment: $V^{model}_{ij}$ is a complex (M x 1) vector ands so is $V_{ij}$.

Comment: I'm confused by that. Are you saying that for each $i,j$, $V_{ij}$ is an $M \times 1$ vector? That is, $V$ could be thought of as an $N \times N \times M$ tensor?

Comment: Oh no, what I meant was that for each i,j $V_{ij}$ is a complex number. In total the number of "data points/ $V_{ij}$measurements" is M.

Comment: okay that makes sense then, and my calculations should all be correct in that case. They're still not particularly easy to follow though; sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the $\sigma_{ij}$ are known.

Let $\Sigma$ denote the matrix with entries $\sigma_{ij}$.  Let $U$ denote the matrix
$$
U = \exp\operatorname{diag}(\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3) = \pmatrix{e^{i\phi_1 }\\ & e^{i \phi_2}\\ & & e^{i \phi_3}}.
$$
Note that the matrix whose entries are $V_{ij}g_ig_j^*$ can be written as $UVU^*$.  With that, your objective function can be expressed as
$$
S = \sum_{i,j} \frac{1}{\sigma^2_{ij}}|V_{ij} - g_i g^*_j V^{model}_{ij}|^2 = \|\Sigma \odot (V - UV^{\text{model}}U^*)\|_F^2,
$$
where $\odot$ denotes a Hadamard product. With that, a gradient with respect to the vector $\phi = (\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3)$ can be computed.

---

We have:
$$
dS = d\|\Sigma\odot(V - UV^MU^*)\|_F^2 = 
2 \operatorname{Re}\operatorname{tr}[(\Sigma\odot(V - UV^MU^*))^*d(\Sigma\odot(V - UV^MU^*))].
\\
d[\Sigma\odot(V - UV^MU^*)] = \Sigma \odot d(UV^MU^*).\\
d [UV^MU^*] = U(\phi + d\phi)V^MU^*(\phi + d\phi) - UV^MU^* \\
= U V^M[\operatorname{diag}(i e^{i\phi}d\phi)]^*
+ [\operatorname{diag}(i e^{i\phi}d\phi)]V^MU^*.\\
$$
To find the entries of the gradient, plug in $dx = e_j$ (the standard basis vectors). We have $dx = e_j \implies$
$$
d [UV^MU^*] = UV^M\operatorname{diag}(i e^{i\phi_j} e_j)^* + 
\operatorname{diag}(i e^{i\phi_j} e_j)V^MU^*\\
= -ie^{-i\phi_j} U (V^M e_j)e_j^T  + 
ie^{i\phi_j}e_j(e_j^T V^M)V^MU^*.\\
d[\Sigma\odot(V - UV^MU^*)] = 
\Sigma \odot [-ie^{-i\phi_j} U (V^M e_j)e_j^T  + 
ie^{i\phi_j}e_j(e_j^T V^M)V^MU^*].\\
dS =\\ 
2 \operatorname{Re}\operatorname{tr}[(\Sigma\odot(V - UV^MU^*))^*(\Sigma \odot [-ie^{-i\phi_j} U (V^M e_j)e_j^T  + 
ie^{i\phi_j}e_je_j^TV^MU^*])]
\\ = 
2 \operatorname{Re}\operatorname{tr}[\Sigma^{\odot2} \odot ((V - UV^MU^*)^*[-ie^{-i\phi_j} U (V^M e_j)e_j^T  + 
ie^{i\phi_j}e_je_j^T V^MU^*])]
\\ = 
2 \operatorname{Re}[
-ie^{-i\phi_j}
e_j^T( \Sigma^{\odot2} \odot [(V - UV^MU^*)^* U V^M ])e_j\\
\quad +ie^{-i\phi_j}
e_j^T( \Sigma^{\odot2} \odot [(V - UV^MU^*)^*  V^MU^*])e_j].
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you be able to work out the calculation of the gradient?

Comment: @Sketos I will if I get the chance later today. It's a bit involved, but ultimately straightforward

Comment: Appreciate it if it's not too much trouble. There are symbols in there that I have not seen before and might take too long to convince myself that I am doing everything right.

Comment: thank you for providing a derivation of the gradient. Correct if I am wrong but in order to find the exact solution for the vector $\phi$ I need to set the gradient $dS/d\phi = 0$. This would give me a expression of the following form:

$sin\phi [\Sigma^{\odot 2} \odot [(V - U V^M U^*)^* U V^M] - \Sigma^{\odot 2} \odot [(V - U V^M U^*)^* V^M U*]]= 0$

I don't see how I getting a solution for $\phi$. Am I missing something (or did I mess up the calculation)?